# integer list -> long switch/case - better readability

Tags: java, switch-statement, code-readability

I have the following values:

```
public int TYP_SOMEONE = 1, TYP_SOMETWO = 2, TYP_SOMESPECIAL = 433,
    TYP_SOMETHREE = 3, .., TYP_SOMENINETYNINE = 99;
```

They are used in at least 5 methods throughout the code. 
At one place there's a long switch-case list where these values are used
to assign `String`s the right way:

```
switch ( iTyp ){
    case 1:
      assignedString = "one";
      break
    case 2:
      assignedString = "two";
      break;
}
```

I want to shorten the code. What is a good way to do this? I thought about
enums, but I wonder how, because it's a long task to change in every 
class that uses TYP_xxx the type of the variable and add parentheses and so 
on...

Comment: You know the right answer: enum.  It's not that much work, and future work will be easier because you did it right.  Do it right; use enums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the range of those integer constants is not too large, and it's consecutive, you can use an array to map the integers to the matching Strings. Otherwise, you can do the mapping with a HashMap.

For example :

```
String[] assignments = new String[500];
assignments[1] = "one";
assignments[2] = "two";
...

assignedString = assignments[iTyp];
```

Or with a Map :

```
Map<Integer,String> assignments = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
assignments.put (1, "one");
assignments.put (2, "two");
....

assignedString = assignments.get(iTyp);
```

Comment: As a bonus, using a `HashMap` allows for dynamic configuration.  I'm actually doing that RIGHT NOW.